# How to query Top N ARRAY_MAX in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

My table has a column that is in array type, and each in each row contain an array of length of 100.
I want to get the top 10 value out of each array and I only know how to get top 1 value using `ARRAY_MAX(column)`
How can we get top N value instead?
Getting top N out of an array is different from getting top n value out of a regular column and rows where you can do
`SELECT column \\ FROM table \\ ORDER BY column DESC \\ LIMIT 10`

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the comment Dale, edited tag and removed image.

Comment: We still want to see your sample data, just as formatted text not as an image.

Comment: And table definition since Mysql does not have array datatype. For sample data a representative smaller 'array' size of (say) 3 would do

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you correcting the tag info if the question is not MySQL based ? But if we are indeed using MySQL as the `MySQL` tag  implies or if you are simply curious about how MySQL copes with array, I believe it does not have an array type for columns and not really needs one. This can be accomplished using a primary table with an array_id column and a second table which references the primary table's array_id and stores individual values through each row. The second table may look like this:

```
array_id    array_value
1           443
1           80
1           8088
2           3306
2           1521
3           22
```

Thus the TOP N values can be easily retrieved. If by TOP N values you mean the top N highest values , we can use a similar query as the one you provided: 
`SELECT array_value from array_table where array_id=n ORDER BY array_value DESC LIMIT 10;`

Or if you mean the top n values in terms of the sequence in the array, we can use:
`SELECT array_value from array_table where array_id=n LIMIT 10;` 
In the latter case, no ORDER BY clause is required in this case as we would like to retrieve values based on the sequence of rows being inserted. Usually it's the default sequence for a column's values to show up without index if ORDER BY clause is omitted. However, if you are really worried about the sequence without ORDER BY, you are free to add a timestamp column or PK auto_increment id column and use it in the ORDER BY clause to guarantee the sequence.